# Need Regular Expression for co-ordinates

Tags: java, regex, string, coordinates

I am writing one java code and reading co-ordinates as String in code,
I have multiple co-ordinates like below and want to write Regular Expression to validate the same. Can anybody help ?

```
"51.057,6.76;51.059,6.759;51.062,6.76;51.063,6.76;51.064,6.76;51.067,6.761;51.07,6.762;51.072,6.763;51.074,6.765;51.076,6.767;51.077,6.769;51.078,6.772;51.079,6.776;51.079,6.776;51.079,6.776;51.08,6.78;51.08,6.78;51.081,6.782;51.082,6.783"
```

here, multiple co-ordinates are separated by **;**

and for each co-ordinate, X and Y is separated by **,**

Comment: You might be better off validating by parsing doubles. For one thing, it's not easy writing regexes to validate that decimal points are not doubled

Comment: `want to write Regular Expression to validate the same` - What do you want to validate?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Count the repetitions for 'N' N = 19?
final String RE_COORDS = "(?:\\d+\\.\\d+,\\d+\\.\\d+;)+\\d+\\.\\d+,\\d+\\.\\d+";
```

You might be better off validating by parsing doubles. For one thing, it's not easy writing regexes to validate that decimal points are not doubled

Comment: Thanks for your help, we can not predict the counts of co-ordinates, they can be of any number,

Comment: also, I can not just validate based on the semicolons(;), as I mentioned, the co-ordinates X and Y are separated by comma(,) , and multiple co-ordinates are separated by semicolon(;)

Comment: See correction. You can change the grouped repetition number

Comment: Why use `+` for the non-catching group and not `*` ? This expression will not validate the case where there is only one coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Validate co-ordinates as doubles:

See context and testbench below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String input = "51.057,6.76;51.059,6.759;51.062,6.76;51.063,6.76;51.064,6.76;51.067,6.761;"
            + "51.07,6.762;51.072,6.763;51.074,6.765;51.076,6.767;51.077,6.769;51.078,6.772;"
            + "51.079,6.776;51.079,6.776;51.079,6.776;51.08,6.78;51.08,6.78;51.081,6.782;51.082,6.783;"
            + "A,4.0;BB,53.1";

    List<String> coordinates = Arrays.asList(input.split(";"));

    Pattern splitByCommaPattern = Pattern.compile(",");// Always pre-compile regex before loop

    // Validate that co-ordinates are doubles and store in list as Double
    List<Map<String, Double>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String xyAsString : coordinates) {
        String[] xySplit = splitByCommaPattern.split(xyAsString);
        String xAsString = xySplit[0];
        String yAsString = xySplit[1];
        addXYtoResult(xAsString, yAsString, result);
    }

    System.out.println("\nPrint result:");
    result.forEach(xyMap -> System.out.printf("X = '%s' and Y = '%s' %n", xyMap.get("x"), xyMap.get("y")));

}

private static void addXYtoResult(String xAsString, String yAsString, List<Map<String, Double>> result) {
    try {
        Map<String, Double> xyMap = new HashMap<>();
        xyMap.put("x", Double.parseDouble(xAsString));
        xyMap.put("y", Double.parseDouble(yAsString));
        result.add(xyMap);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.printf("This co-ordinate does not have "
                + "valid number format and cannot be parsed "
                + "to doubles: '%s,%s'.%n", xAsString, yAsString);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This co-ordinate does not have valid number format and cannot be parsed to doubles: 'A,4.0'.
This co-ordinate does not have valid number format and cannot be parsed to doubles: 'BB,53.1'.

Print result:
X = '51.057' and Y = '6.76'
X = '51.059' and Y = '6.759'
X = '51.062' and Y = '6.76'
X = '51.063' and Y = '6.76'
X = '51.064' and Y = '6.76'
X = '51.067' and Y = '6.761'
X = '51.07' and Y = '6.762'
X = '51.072' and Y = '6.763'
X = '51.074' and Y = '6.765'
X = '51.076' and Y = '6.767'
X = '51.077' and Y = '6.769'
X = '51.078' and Y = '6.772'
X = '51.079' and Y = '6.776'
X = '51.079' and Y = '6.776'
X = '51.079' and Y = '6.776'
X = '51.08' and Y = '6.78'
X = '51.08' and Y = '6.78'
X = '51.081' and Y = '6.782'
X = '51.082' and Y = '6.783'
```